# ClickOnce Publish: Install button fails, but launch link works

Tags: .net, clickonce, publish

I have an strange error trying to install an application distributed as a clickonce.

You can reproduce the behaviour here:

https://bank.dev.ivnosys.net/backofficeSSL/

If the user clicks on "launch" link. The installer works perfectly.
However if the user clicks on "Install" button, I get the following error:
[image: Error window]

The install log, doesn't help. This is its content:

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.3.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 4.5', phase BuildList
Looking up path for special folder 'WindowsFolder'
Running check with folder 'C:\Windows\System32' and file 'msi.dll'
Attempting to find file 'C:\Windows\System32\msi.dll'
File version is '5.0.9600.17905'
Setting value '5.0.9600.17905 {version}' for property 'VersionMsiDll'
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 4.5':
Property: [VersionMsiDll] = 5.0.9600.17905 {version}
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22308': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22308': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU' is 'Bypass'
'Windows Installer 4.5' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read string value '4.5.51650'
Setting value '4.5.51650 {string}' for property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet40Full_TargetVersion] = 4.5.51650 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.0.30129': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697191'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'https://bank.dev.ivnosys.net/backofficeSSL/IBANify.application'.
```

I'm 100% sure that the end user will try to click install. For me, It's a big usability problem.

Comment: Possible stupid question - but does `https://bank.dev.ivnosys.net/backofficeSSL/IBANify.application` actually exist?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes. You can try it opening it directly from IE. You will see the installer runs with no problem. Also this URL is the url wich is opened when you click "Launch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error -2146697191 translates to `0x800C0019` which is:

> INET_E_INVALID_CERTIFICATE - The SSL certificate is invalid.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775145(v=vs.85).aspx)

So it looks like your SSL certificate isn't setup correctly for the url you are trying to access.

If you try the link as plain `http` it should work.

But to fix it properly you'll need to sort out the certificate.

Comment: I think you're right, because it's the server which we use for tests. In this server, the certificate used on the IIS is a custom certificate. However I install de Custom CA on my machine as a trusted CA. I think it should be enough. Despite of this, i will try to test directly on production. Maybe the problem will not be replicated.

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk were you able to solve the problem with the SSL certificate from a custom CA? Running into the same problem right now